# Dancer2 not writing anything to a log file or maybe not reading config file

Tags: perl, web-services, logging, dancer

Here's the Dancer2 mini-app:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.14;

use Dancer2;
use File::Slurper qw(read_text);

set content_type => 'application/json';

my $path;
for my $p ( qw( hitos.json /data/hitos.json ./data/hitos.json ../data/hitos.json) ) {
  if ( -r $p ) {
    $path = $p;
  }
}

my $hitos = from_json read_text($path);

get '/status' => sub {
  return to_json { status => 'OK' };
};

get '/all' => sub {
  return to_json $hitos;
};

start;
```

with this configuration file:

```
logger : "File"
engines:
  logger:
    File:
      log_level: core
      log_dir: "/tmp"
      file_name: "p5hitos.log"
```

I have named it `config.yml` and `config.yaml`, and also tried to use the JSON configuration option. I have tried to set the port from it, and it does not "catch" the port setting, so could the problem be the configuration file failing silently? I have also tried to set the configuration on the same file:

```
set content_type => 'application/json';
set logger => "File";
set port => 31415;
set engines => { logger => { File => { log_level => "core",
                       log_dir => ".",
                       file_name => "p5hitos.log" }}};
```

In this case, the port and content-type are set correctly, but still no go, either with this log_dir or with `/tmp`. I have also tried code from [this test](https://github.com/PerlDancer/Dancer2/blob/703d5826177657e756f67b7ef0121ebe1923e5ff/t/issues/gh-634.t) and copied it verbatim (set logger after set engines and low-case `file` were the only differences). It does not change. `config` is still the same:

```
0  HASH(0x2a3d070)
   'appdir' => '/home/jmerelo/'
   'apphandler' => 'Standalone'
   'behind_proxy' => 0
   'charset' => ''
   'content_type' => 'application/json'
   'engines' => HASH(0x2947a58)
      'logger' => HASH(0x2947008)
         'File' => HASH(0xa438b0)
            'file_name' => 'p5hitos.log'
            'log_dir' => '/tmp'
   'environment' => 'development'
   'host' => '0.0.0.0'
   'logger' => Dancer2::Logger::File=HASH(0x2a7ef58)
      'app_name' => 'main'
      'config' => HASH(0x2a7f1b0)
           empty hash
      'environment' => 'development'
      'file_name' => 'p5hitos.log'
      'location' => '/home/jmerelo/'
      'log_dir' => '/tmp'
      'log_format' => '[%a:%P] %L @%T> %m in %f l. %l'
      'log_level' => 'debug'
   'no_server_tokens' => 0
   'port' => 31415
   'public_dir' => '/home/jmerelo/public'
   'route_handlers' => ARRAY(0x2779490)
      0  ARRAY(0x27791d8)
         0  'AutoPage'
         1  1
   'startup_info' => 1
   'static_handler' => undef
   'template' => 'Tiny'
   'traces' => 0
   'views' => '/home/jmerelo/views'
```

It starts up and returns the two routes correctly, but the log file is not created and obviously nothing is written on it. There's no error either on the console, and it's not logging to it either. It just shows the startup message: `>> Dancer2 v0.204001 server 16427 listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000`. The Log file object seems to have been created correctly, but it does not respond. Any idea?

Comment: Regarding your first problem (ensuring that 'config.yml' is actually being read), it might be worth checking that permissions are set correctly on the config file (i.e. that the user under which plackup / Starman is being run actually has permission to read it). And - just in case - that it's in the correct directory (root for PSGI application)?

Comment: What is your directory structure for this project?

Comment: It's just what you see there, that simple file and the config file, both in the same directory, same privs, and running as user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`app.psgi` looks like this:

```
use v5.14;
use Dancer2;
set content_type => 'application/json';
get '/' => sub {
    debug "Hello World";
    return to_json config;
};
start;
```

In the same directory `config.yml` looks like this:

```
param: Foo
logger : "File"
engines:
  logger:
    File:
      log_level: core
      log_dir: "/tmp"
      file_name: "p5hitos.log"
```

I launch the application as `plackup app.psgi` and then access it from another window as `curl http://0:5000/ | jq`

The log entry is saved in the /tmp/p5hitos.log as expected and in the output on the command line I can see all the configuration values. Both the default ones and the ones I provided.

Comment: It mainly works now, so thanks. I still can't figure out what was the problem. However, there are a couple of things that do not work now: I try to set `port: 31415
content_type: "application/json"` in the configuration file and it just does not do anything, it's still using the default settings. Setting content_type on the program does not work either. Any idea?

Comment: Coming back here because I'm finding the same problem, 3 years later...  The only difference I see between your set up and mine is that you use "start" instead of "dance".  What's the deal with param: Foo also?

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Ensuring the configuration file is read

My only suggestions here are

1. Ensure that you have the YAML module installed.
2. Check the *permissions* on the configuration file - i.e. that the user running the script has read permissions.
3. Check the location and name of the configuration file. It should be one of the the following: a) `appdir/config.yml`, b) `appdir/environments/development.yml`, or c) `appdir/environments/production.yml` (where `appdir` is where your Dancer application is located). See [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Manual#CONFIGURATION) for more info.

You also mentioned that you

> tried to use the JSON configuration option.

I'm not sure what you mean by this. (The configuration file is written in YAML - not JSON.)

### 2. Logging configuration

You wrote above that

> I have also tried code from this test and copied it verbatim (set logger after set engines and low-case file were the only differences)

I think this might be one of your problems. If you are setting the configuration programmatically (i.e. not in the configuration file), try placing

```
set logger => 'File';
```

*after*

```
set engines => { ...`
```

I.e., instead of

```
set logger => 'File';
set engines => {
    logger => {
        File => {
            log_dir => $log_dir,
            log_level => $log_level,
            file_name => $log_filename,
        }
    }
};
```

try the following.

```
set engines => {
    logger => {
        File => {
            log_dir => $log_dir,
            log_level => $log_level,
            file_name => $log_filename,
        }
    }
};
set logger => 'File';
```

The second approach works for me. The former doesn't.

[1](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Manual#CONFIGURATION) https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Manual#CONFIGURATION .

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not work either. In fact, that was my last test, only I used 'file' instead of 'File'. I have upgraded Perl to 5.24, Dancer2 to v0.205002 but no joy. Is there some version magic going on?