# Dancer2 failing to read the configuration file quietly

Tags: perl, dancer2

> This is more or less [the same problem I had here with the log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269556/dancer2-not-writing-anything-to-a-log-file-or-maybe-not-reading-config-file), with a bit of more information and a different configuration

With this configuration file (in the root directory):

```yaml
port: 31415
content_type: "application/json"
engines:
  logger:
    File:
      log_level: core
      file_name: "p5hitos.log"
logger: "File"
```

and this main program (`hitos.psgi`, same directory):

```perl
use v5.14;
use lib qw(lib);

use My::Hitos;
use Dancer2 appname => 'My::Hitos';

dance;
```

> Routes are included into another file, I'm not sure it's really necessary here, but all code is [here](https://github.com/JJ/p5-hitos))

the program fails to read the configuration. Funny thing is, if I put the last line first, it fails to log in any way. Putting "logger" as the last line in the file it logs to the console, not to the place I configured. It's also failing to set the port, or the default content_type. The [manual](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer2/lib/Dancer2/Config.pod#MANIPULATING-SETTINGS-VIA-CONFIGURATION-FILES) seems to imply there's some setting that says the configuration file we'll be using. Not totally clear what that setting would be, or how to set it, or what's actually the default configuration file extension. Any idea?

**Update**: I have copied config.yml to `lib/My`... and well, it looks like it's reading it, because `runner` actually has those features in the configuration, and it does says a message. It's also logging... something, and to console:

```
We are logging Entering hook core.error.afterWe are logging
We are logging looking for get /statusWe are logging
We are logging Entering hook core.app.before_requestWe are logging
```

(after setting the `export DANCER_CONFIG_VERBOSE=1`). Still not doing it to the configured place.

Comment: Where do you save the configuration file?

Comment: @choroba same directory as the app. Will clarify.

Comment: Have you started from the scaffolding created by the `dancer2 -a`?

Comment: @choroba no, I started from a single script.

Comment: So maybe try the scaffolding and compare the differences?